# Get output from Bash in Java?

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I have this this Java code that works:

```
public class GetNumberOfFiles {
    protected long GetNumberOfFilesMethod(String folder){
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd " + folder + "&& find . -type f | grep :*.txt "});
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            return stdInput.lines().count();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

I created also this code with similar logic, but after a few tries I put the bash code into  a separate file.

The Java code:

```
protected String CheckUserMethod(String user){
        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "~/Final-Year/src/query", "&& ./checkuser.sh", user});
            BufferedReader srdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String a = null;
            while ((a = srdInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }

            return a;
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The bash code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2237
if ! [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "$1"
  cd ~/Final-Year/maps/ && find "$1" -maxdepth 0 -type d -printf 1
fi
```

The code is working perfectly when I am executing from terminal as it is in this example:

[image]

The problem is,when I am executing the code from Java is not even executing the bash file. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `bash -c`, the first argument after the `-c` is treated as a command, and any additional arguments are passed as positional parameters.

In your first fragment,

```
{"bash", "-c", "cd " + folder + "&& find . -type f | grep :*.txt "}
```

you are passing a single concatenated string argument `"cd " + folder + "&& find . -type f | grep :*.txt "` whereas in the second fragment,

```
{"bash", "-c", "~/Final-Year/src/query", "&& ./checkuser.sh", user}
```

you are passing 3 arguments:

- `~/Final-Year/src/query` (which presumably should have been `cd ~/Final-Year/src/query`
- `&& ./checkuser.sh`
- `user`

so it's equivalent to

```
bash -c '~/Final-Year/src/query' '&& ./checkuser.sh' user
```

which executes `bash -c '~/Final-Year/src/query'` or (corrected) `bash -c 'cd ~/Final-Year/src/query'` with literal string `&& ./checkuser.sh` as positional parameter `$0` and the substituted Java variable `user` as positional parameter `$1`

What you likely want is

```
bash -c 'cd ~/Final-Year/src/query && ./checkuser.sh user'
```

which would instead be

```
{"bash", "-c", "cd ~/Final-Year/src/query && ./checkuser.sh " + user}
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the positional parameter array like

```
{"bash", "-c", "cd ~/Final-Year/src/query && ./checkuser.sh \"$1\"", "bash", user}
```

where the shell's name `bash` is passed as `$0` (you could use any arbitrary string here) and Java variable `user` as `$1`.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Thank you so much for your help!